# Why Junit TestRunner cannot find the features?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, test-runner

I am working with `cucumber` and `selenium` project and I am trying to run the test by a `Junit Test Runner`. Here is [the complete code](https://github.com/salman-/Friday) (make sure you have lombok in your IDE). And here is my `test runner`:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features            = {"src/test/resources/features" }, 
        monochrome = true,
        plugin              = {
                "pretty",
                "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/report.html"
        },
        tags                = {"@all"},
        glue                = {"stepDefinitions"}
        )
public class TestRunnerJUnit {

    @AfterClass
    public static void setup() {
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("User Name", System.getProperty("user.name"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Time Zone", System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Machine", "Windows 10" + "64 Bit");
        Reporter.setTestRunnerOutput("Sample test runner output message");
    }

}
```

The point is, when i run the test using the test runner, it finds the feature file, but it does not find any Scenario inside it. Here is the output of the run:

```
@all
Feature: 
  As a customer, I should be able to register for insurance.

0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s
```

if i run the test directly using the feature file (by right click on it `Run as Cucumber` then it works well. But, i need to run my test by test runner)

Comment: Try removing the second `@all` from the feature file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a chance to pull your code base and look into the code.
the issue you are running into is something to do with extent library. **you are providing feature name in a new line** and which extent library can't understand that. write feature name in same line and it should solve your problem

```
Feature: As a customer, I should be able to register for insurance.
```

I  also suggest you to use newer version of cucumber (Cucumber-JVM v4+) libraries which have concurrent  execution support( under single JVM) and current library which you are using going to span up multiple JVM instances depending on your configuration